# How to use latest SWT in Eclipse RCP4 application?

Tags: eclipse, swt, rcp

I have two question about using SWT in Eclipse RCP4 application?

Q1: Why Eclipse 4x (Luna, Mars, Neon, Oxygen..) still use SWT 3.x but not 4.x? I downloaded SWT build with Eclipse Neon project (http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.6.1-201609071200/), but it is not the SWT which is used by Eclipse Neon.

Q2: When I created new RCP4 application by Eclipse Neon, this RCP4 application used the SWT library which is used by Eclipse Neon (SWT 3.x). How can I use SWT 4.x in my RCP4 application and How can Maven-Tycho build SWT 4.x for this application?

Answer (score 1):

The SWT included with Eclipse Neon is the same as this download.

The download is numbered 4.6.1 to show that it is part of the Eclipse 4.6.1 (Neon.1) release. The SWT plugin version is 3.105.1. All 4.6.1 downloads include the same SWT.

You can also look at the `libxxx-4626.xxx` files in the two jars. The `4626` is in internal SWT version (4.626).

You can also call `SWT.getVersion()` which returns `4626` (the internal version) in both cases.

So there is nothing to do.

Comment: I compared org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.105.1.v20160907-0248.jar in  eclipse-SDK-4.6.1-win32-x86_64.zip and swt.jar in swt-4.6.1-win32-win32-x86_64.zip. They are very different. So, why can you say them swt 4.6.1 is swt 3.105.1?

Comment: One is built as an Eclipse plugin and the other is a plain jar.

Comment: Added a note about the SWT internal version number and how to check it.